# Trouble understanding One-One and Onto function.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

So I have a question like this:

> Let $g$ be a function $g : \mathbb{Z} → \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ such that $g(n) = (2n, n + 3)$.

And I want to find if this is **onto** and **one-one**. But I'm having a hard time understanding the concept of it.

For $one-one$, I understand that each input has one unique output ($2$ different inputs cannot have the same output) $g(n)$ such that $x ≠ y$

And I get 
$f(x) = (2x, x+3)$ and $f(y) = (2y, y+3)$

And now I'm stuck, and can't figure out how or why they are equal or not.

And then for **onto**, Every output should have be related to at least one input. But am completely lost in how to prove the function is onto.

I have checked other questions on the site, but can only get a few things out of the, and never fully understand

Answer (score 2):

To prove that $g$ is injective, you assume $g(x)=g(y)$ and try to prove $x=y$. So assume $g(x)=g(y).$ Then $(2x,x+3)=(2y,y+3)$. Hence $2x=2y$. So $x=y$.

You write: "But am completely lost in how to prove the function is onto." That's because the function is not onto! To show this, try to prove that $(1,0)$ is not in the image of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

First, injectivity: by cancellation, either cancelling the $2$'s in $2x=2y$ or the $3$ in $x+3=y+3$, you can find that $x=y$, so $g(x)=g(y)$ if and only if $x=y$.

For showing that the function *isn't* onto (because it isn't!), think about what values the first component of $g(n)$ can take on.  Can every integer be expressed as $2n$ for some $n$?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why they downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

If $n \not = m$, then $(2n,n+3) \not =(2m,m+3)$ and therefore the function is one-to-one.

Also, you can never find $x$ such that $f(x)=(0,0)$. So, the function is not onto.